# How to return client IP address in loopback 4?

Tags: loopback4

I want to return either IPv4/IPv6 IP in the loopback4 application? How do I modify the below code to get IP address?

```
import {get, param} from '@loopback/rest';

    export class GreetController {       
      @get('/', {
        responses: {
          '200': {
            description: 'greeting text',
            content: {
              'application/json': {
                schema: {type: 'string'},
              },
            },
          },
        },
      })
      greet(@param.query.string('name') name: string) {
        return `hello ${name}`;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The LoopBack 4 Request object extends Express.js' equivalent:

```js
import {
  get,
  param,
  Request,
  RestBindings
} from '@loopback/rest';

export class GreetController {
  constructor(
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST) private _request: Request,
  ) {}
  @get('/', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'greeting text',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {type: 'string'},
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  greet(@param.query.string('name') name: string) {
    return `hello ${name}, your ip address is ${this._request.ip}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: And if you use a load balancer or cloudflare you'll get the load balancer ip all the time. You need to get the header X-Forwarded-For  like this `this._request.headers['x-forwarded-for'];`